# Loop to check sums, depending on several columns with unknown entries

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am dealing with data validation in Excel VBA.

I receive lists of employees, dates and quantities, and before further processing I need to check if ANY employee (column A) at ANY date (column B) had more than a certain total quantity of something (column C; conditional sum).

As an example, let's assume I want to check incoming sheets of the following format:

[image: Example]

… and I need to raise a warning, if any employee had more than one full cookie on any day. (In the example, it should raise a warning, because Ben had 1.2 cookies on Jan 1ˢᵗ.)

Assumptions:

- I do not know which names are on the list.
- I do not know how many entries per day this person had.
- I do not know the order of the entries in the incoming sheets.

My current approach would be to filter columns A and B for unique values, loop over these two lists and apply a SumIfS to sum the respective values in column C. This seems totally inefficient however, as it involves many nested loops, and it is rather the "Excel"-way than the "VBA" way.

How can I solve this problem using VBA properly?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) to get the total amount of cookies each employee had a single day:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A:A,B:B,B:B) 'alternatively =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2)

=IF(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A:A,B:B,B:B) > 1,A:A & " is too fat", A:A & " can eat more")
```

For german Excel use:

```
=SUMMEWENNS(C:C;A:A;A:A;B:B;B:B) 'alternatively =SUMMEWENNS(C:C;A:A;A2;B:B;B2)

=WENN(SUMMEWENNS(C:C;A:A;A:A;B:B;B:B) > 1;A:A & " is too fat"; A:A & " can eat more")
```

[image]

If you need a VBA solution have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.SumIfs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sumifs) or just write that formula with VBA into the column:

```
Range("E2:E20").Formula = "=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A:A,B:B,B:B)" '<-- takes only english formula
```

eg. to use it for easy filtering later (eg. to get a list of all fat employees).